# Someone who has logged in to your app with Facebook in the past logs back in

Tags: ios, facebook

Go to your app and tap on the “Log in with Facebook” button

Tap OK to accept the read permissions (and OK again to accept write permissions where applicable)

Uninstall then re-install your app

Open your app and tap on the “Log in with Facebook” button

Verify that you can log in without seeing any permission dialogs

I am trying to test above condition in my iOS (iPhone/iPad) application, but it shows permission dialog after reinstalling application.

I am adding login/logout buttun as follows, What should I check to avoid showing premission dialog for above condition

```
FBLoginView *m_fbLoginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"friends_photos", @"user_photos"]];
m_fbLoginview.delegate = self;
[myDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:m_fbLoginview];
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why this was happening.
Settings for application was not complete.

- Login to facebook account
- Go to settings
- click on +Add Platform
- Choose iOS
- Add Bundle ID
- Store IDs - if you have
- Set "Single Sign On" to YES

You are done, this solved the problem